# Iterative %DO LOOP issue in SAS macro for automated emailing of site metrics

Tags: email, sas, macros, iteration, do-loops

I have a dataset titled 'SampleReport' of site specific reporting metrics and am looking to email each site their own metrics in an attached PDF. The PDFs generate and are emailed out to their respective sites, however when trying to add ODS text to the PDF, I'm having issues defining my other macros (currently only 'email' is retained as a macro variable but I also want 'site', 'Site_Contact' and 'mcnt_enrolled').

Below is the test dataset and my code; I'm new to SAS and would appreciate any help/suggestions:

```
    site    site_enrolled_total mcnt_enrolled   Site_Contact    Email   Expected_Enrolled   NetworkAvg  Overall_Study_Enrollment    Overall_Enrollment_to_Date
site_a  32  7   Homer Simpson   hsimp@gmail.com 40  5   115 1518
site_b  36  8   Jim Schoe   jimmy2schoes@aol.com    40  4   115 1518
site_ c 20  2   Hank Hill   propaneking@yahoo.com   36  7   115 1518
site_d  27  7   Lisa Simpson    lisasimpson@gmail.com   36  5   115 1518
```

And here's my code:

```
    %macro getemail(DATA);
    ods _all_ close;
    %let outdir = %sysfunc(getoption(WORK));
    OPTIONS NODATE NONUMBER;
    ODS GRAPHICS / RESET=ALL;

    ** get list of unique emails;
    proc sql noprint;
        select distinct(email) into :wantemail separated by '~'
            from samplereport
                order by email;
    quit;
    %put &=wantemail;
    **count number of separators(i.e. '~') and count number of unique emails;
    %let cntsep1 = %sysfunc(count(&wantemail,~));
    %let cntemail = %eval(&cntsep1+1);
    ** start do loop to cycle thru list of emails;
    ** and create the site macro var for each loop;
    %do i = 1 %to &cntemail;
        %let email = %scan(&wantemail,&i,~);
        %put This is for by group where email = &email;


    **use site macro variable for file name and WHERE and TITLE;
        ODS PDF (id=dagwood)
            FILE="&outdir.\PDF_&email..PDF" STARTPAGE=NO STYLE=Journal gtitle;
title j=center bold "Metrics for January 2020"; 
ods text= "Email: &email. ";
ods text= "Site: &site. ";
ods text= "Site Contact: &Site_Contact.";
ods text= "Enrolled this Month: &mcnt_enrolled. ";
run;

        ods layout gridded columns=2;
        ods graphics / width=300 height=300;
ods region;
    ods pdf(id=dagwood) style=statdoc;

    PROC SGPLOT DATA=work.samplereport;
        where email = "&email";
        Title "Enrollment Metrics for Your Site";
        vbar site / response=Expected_Enrolled stat=sum DATALABEL LEGENDLABEL="Expected Enrollment for Your Site"
            discreteoffset=-0.5 barwidth=0.2 fillattrs=graphdata2;
        yaxis grid display=(nolabel);
        xaxis display=(noline NOTICKS NOVALUES nolabel);
        vbar site / response=site_enrolled_total stat=sum DATALABEL LEGENDLABEL="Enrolled for Your Site to Date"
            discreteoffset=-0.2 barwidth=0.2 fillattrs=graphdata1;
        yaxis grid display=(nolabel);
        xaxis display=(noline NOTICKS NOVALUES nolabel);
        vbar site / response=mcnt_enrolled stat=sum DATALABEL LEGENDLABEL="Enrolled this Month"
            discreteoffset=0.2 barwidth=0.2 fillattrs=graphdata3;
        yaxis grid display=(nolabel);
        xaxis display=(noline NOTICKS NOVALUES nolabel);
        vbar site / response=NetworkAvg stat=sum DATALABEL LEGENDLABEL="Your Network Avg Enrollment this Month"
            discreteoffset=0.5 barwidth=0.2 fillattrs=graphdata4;
        yaxis grid display=(nolabel);
        xaxis display=(noline NOTICKS NOVALUES nolabel);
    RUN;

ods region;
    ods pdf(id=dagwood) style=statdoc;
    goptions reset=all;

    proc sgplot data=work.samplereport;
        where email = "&email";
        Title "Study-Wide Enrollment to Date and Goal";
        vbar site / response=Overall_Study_Enrollment stat=sum DATALABEL LEGENDLABEL="Enrollment for All Sites"
            discreteoffset=-0.3 barwidth=0.4 fillattrs=graphdata5;
        yaxis grid display=(nolabel);
        xaxis display=(noline NOTICKS NOVALUES nolabel);
        vbar site / response=Overall_Expected_Study stat=sum DATALABEL LEGENDLABEL="Expected Enrollment Goal"
            discreteoffset=0.3 barwidth=0.4 fillattrs=graphdata6;
        yaxis grid display=(nolabel);
        xaxis display=(noline NOTICKS NOVALUES nolabel);
    run;

ODS LAYOUT END;
    %end;

    * get emails from DATA;
    proc sql noprint;
        select EMAIL into :EMAIL1- from &DATA;
        select count(*) into :EMAILN from &DATA;

        * cycle through emails;
        %do I=1 %to &EMAILN;
        filename temp email to="&&EMAIL&I"
        attach="&outdir.\PDF_&&email&I...PDF"
        from="myemail@gmail.com"
            type="text/html"
            subject="Site Metrics";
            ods html file=temp;
    run;

    ods html close;
        %end;
%mend getemail;

%getemail(samplereport);
```

Comment: What’s the value of your variables eg &wantsite, &cntsep and &cntsite? Maybe there’s a new row with a blank value for site in your data, which can happen eg if it’s coming in from csv and the csv has a linefeed after the last row

Comment: I've fixed the EMAIL5 issue with terminating the %DO loop, however I'm having an issue defining my other macro variables besides 'email'.

Answer (score 1):

The email `%DO` loop statement is not properly terminated.

```
    * cycle through emails;
    %do I=1 %to &EMAILN
```

Should be

```
    * cycle through emails;
    %do I=1 %to &EMAILN;
```

And maybe the `ODS HTML CLOSE` should be outside the loop.